# What do you call someone who wants to be by themselves, but wants others to show they care

Tags: single-word-requests

Like I want to be a lone a lot, but I want a text from someone asking me if I want to hang out. Or someone to text me first. Make it seem like they actually randomly think of me and care. I'm always texting people first and asking them. I just want their reassurance that they still have me somewhere in their minds.

Comment: Perfectly normal I'd say

Comment: Try Googling "JK Rowling is an introvert."

Comment: We all have moments when we want to be alone, but to know that we still have friends out there. But I am not sure what they are called.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of words for wanting to be [completely] alone, some with negative connotations but many without. My preference for those would be withdrawn

However, there is, between introvert and extrovert, **[ambivert](https://www.google.com/search?q=ambivert%20definition)**

> noun
>  plural noun: ambiverts
>  a person who has a balance of
>   extrovert and introvert features in their personality.

(Google)

> coined by Kimball Young in "Source Book for Social Psychology" (1927)

[according to etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambivert)

Maybe that would be appropriate here (if we regard introvert as too withdrawn).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're being **[insecure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/insecure)**.

> not confident about yourself or your relationships with other people

Answer (score -2):

It may be:
1): OFFISHNESS
2): ALOOFNESS
3): DETACHMENT
or even 
a) STANDOFFISHNESS or so to say a person reserved by nature with a kind of 'quietness' about him/her ,but involved nodoubt.